# search and count by gender and race

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to know any ideas for me to find gender and race. The data should display like:

```
-----------------------------
course   | Malay  | chinese | 
         | M | F  |  M | F  |
-----------------------------
science  | 0 | 1  |  0 | 0  |
-----------------------------
business | 0 | 0  | 1  | 0  |
```

//this is table structure

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE student (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
gender VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
race VARCHAR(50),
session VARCHAR(50),
course VARCHAR(50),
)";
```

the example data

---

### id       |  name  | gender |  race   | session    | course

### 98773552 | nurul  | female | malay   | june2014   | science computer

5273544  | lee    | male   | chinese | june2012   | business studies

The code that I already have:

```
<?php
include "connect_db.php";
if ((isset($_POST['submit'])) AND ($_POST['search'] <> "")) {

    $search = $_POST['search'];

    $sql = "SELECT gender, count(gender) AS cnt FROM student WHERE session LIKE '%$search%' AND gender IN ('Male', 'Female') GROUP BY gender" or die(mysqli_error(
        ''
    ));
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $dataSet->addPoint(new Point($row['gender'], $row['cnt']));

    }

}
```

Comment: there is too much missing in your code. do more research, and build up the code. i don't think anyone here will write out the code for you, unless you have a specific question. for starters, did you try running this code? look up the errors and try correcting

Comment: How is your table structure?

Comment: At least you should have given the table sructure. I am not able to find any relation between the given trial code and expected output. Also please try something yourself first.

Comment: @csaw I bet someone will :-(

Answer (score 0):

As an initial idea, you want to generate a result set with all the possible combinations in it.

Ideally you would have a table of genders, a table of races and a table of courses, then you can just cross join those to get all the combinations, then left join the student table to get the counts.

Failing that you can use sub queries to get the possible values, giving you something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT c.course,
                r.race,
                g.gender,
                COUNT(s.id)
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT race
            FROM student
        ) r
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT gender
            FROM student
            WHERE gender IN ('Male', 'Female')
        ) g
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT course
            FROM student
        ) c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN student s
        ON r.race = s.race
        AND g.gender = s.gender
        AND c.course = s.course
        AND session LIKE '%".$conn->escape($search)."%' 
        GROUP BY c.course, r.race, g.gender" or die(mysqli_error(''));
```

Then just the easy php to put this out in a table, putting out a new row of the table when the course changes.

EDIT

Following is completely untested, but hopefully gives you an idea of how to echo out the table, with the 2 heading rows:-

```
<?php

include "connect_db.php";
if ((isset($_POST['submit'])) AND ($_POST['search'] <> "")) 
{

    $search = $_POST['search'];

$sql = "SELECT c.course,
                r.race,
                g.gender,
                COUNT(s.id) AS res_cnt
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT race
            FROM student
        ) r
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT gender
            FROM student
            WHERE gender IN ('Male', 'Female')
        ) g
        CROSS JOIN
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT course
            FROM student
        ) c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN student s
        ON r.race = s.race
        AND g.gender = s.gender
        AND c.course = s.course
        AND session LIKE '%".$conn->escape($search)."%' 
        GROUP BY c.course, r.race, g.gender" or die(mysqli_error(
        ''
    ));
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    echo "<table>";
    $header1 = "<tr><td rowspan='2'>course</td>";
    $header2 = "<tr>";
    $out_row = "<tr>";
    $prev_course = '';
    $prev_race = '';
    $first_row = true;
    while ($row = $conn->fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        if ($prev_course != $row['course'] and $prev_course != '')
        {
            if ($first_row)
            {
                echo $header1."</tr>";
                echo $header2."</tr>";
                $first_row = false;
            }
            echo $out_row."</tr>";
            $out_row = "<tr>";
            $prev_course = $row['course'];
        }
        if ($first_row)
        {
            if ($prev_race != $row['race'])
            {
                $header1 .= "<td colspan='2'>".$row['race']."</td>";
                $prev_race = $row['race'];
            }
            $header2 .= "<td>".$row['gender']."</td>";
        }
        $out_row .= "<td>".$row['res_cnt']."</td>";
    }
    if ($prev_course != $row['course'] and $prev_course != '')
    {
        if ($first_row)
        {
            echo $header1."</tr>";
            echo $header2."</tr>";
            $first_row = false;
        }
        echo $out_row."</tr>";
        $out_row = "<tr>";
        $prev_course = $row['course'];
    }
    echo "</table>";

}
```

Comment: You need to escape the search string. I just guess that the connection class you were using had an escape method. If not change that to the appropriate method you have available.

Comment: can you show me how to put out in table using php....because i try and get error...

Comment: Added a suggestion, but it is completely untested. The 2 header rows are a pain which makes the code awkward.

Comment: i got the Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\t_2.php on line 65 <br/>  while ($row = fetch_assoc($result))

Comment: Can you post a bit of test data and then I will try testing it.

Comment: so if i choose from the dropdown menu session june2014 and the data will display same like the first i post...